# Filtering using predicates

Tags: java

I have used predicates before to filter collections as follows:

```
package com.byhiras.predicate;

import com.byhiras.domain.Bid;
import com.byhiras.domain.User;
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;

/**
 * List of predicates pertinent to User
 */

public class UserPredicate {

    /**
     * Is a bid made by a particular user?
     *
     * @param usr
     * @return
     */
    public static Predicate<Bid> isBidByUser(User usr) {
        return p -> p.getUser().getName().equals(usr.getName());
    }
}
```

For the above I used Java 8 and the latest Guava library. However I'm working on an assignment where I am restricted to Java 6 and version 13.0.1 of Guava with zero chance of getting them to update their maven repo.

I am struggling to get a similar type of predicate done in Java 6 as the use of lambda expressions is not allowed.

I would appreciate any help to port this code to Java 6. Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far with Java 6.

Comment: That's the problem. I can't get a hook onto an element in the collection like I did with the example in the post.

Comment: The usual pre-Java-8 way of doing things is with anonymous inner classes.  Have you tried those?

Comment: Then show us the code you have tried, not the code that works but that you can't use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical, pre-Java-8 way of doing things looks like

```
public static Predicate<Bid> isBidByUser(final User usr) {
    return new Predicate<Bid>() {
      @Override public boolean apply(Bid p) {
        return p.getUser().getName().equals(usr.getName());
      }
    };
}
```